# How to gracefully exit Qemu VM with running kernel

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, gdb

To make sure that my prerequisite knowledge is even correct, I'll first explain what I'm doing (or think that I'm doing).

I'm going through a tutorial on running a Yocto Linux kernel inside the Qemu VM. In a directory, I have sourced an environment script (provided by said tutorial) and a built kernel (based on a config file also provided by the tutorial so I didn't have to choose any setup options- it was all automated once I executed `make -j4 all`)

In that directory I ran Qemu using a long command that includes the port for running `gdb` in another terminal where I `target rmote localhost:xxxx`.

Back in the original terminal with Qemu now running after `continue` in the `gdb` instance, I can login as root and play around with the environment.

**How do I gracefully exit the Qemu VM/terminal?**

When I run `shutdown now` the terminal hangs on `Unmounting remote filesystem...`